# Replace Image in PDF with another Image pdf box

Tags: image, pdf, pdfbox

How to replace Image in PDF with another Image  pdf box. How to do that?

I want to change VisualSignature on the pdf with another image.

I get Visual Apereance like that:

```
PDDocument doc= PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\template.pdf")); 
File dir= new File("c:\\temp\\");

Iterator<Entry<COSObjectKey, Long>> xrefEntriesIt =
    doc.getDocument().getXrefTable().entrySet().iterator();
while( xrefEntriesIt.hasNext() ) {
    COSObject object = doc.getDocument().getObjectFromPool(
        xrefEntriesIt.next().getKey() );
    if ( object.getDictionaryObject( COSName.SUBTYPE ) == COSName.IMAGE ) {
        changeImage( object, doc);
    }
}
```

and method for to change image

```
private static void changeImage(COSObject obj, PDDocument doc) {

    PDXObjectImage imageInPdf =
        (PDXObjectImage) PDXObject.createXObject(
            (COSStream) obj.getObject());

    File inputFile = new File("C:\\temp\\SIGNATURE.jpg");
    PDXObjectImage newImage = new PDJpeg(
        doc, new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    imageInPdf.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(newImage.getCOSStream());
}
```

I tested. imageInPdf is rally image from visual appearance of a signed signature field.

now how to remove and add new visual appearance of a signed signature field?

Comment: Do you mean the visual appearance of a signed signature field? Or an yet-unsigned, empty one?

Comment: I've just update my post. yes , appearance of a signed signature field. I get that Image. from COSObject. but cant change it.

Answer (score 3):

I've just added `doc.save()`. that's all